# Django/Python http.server access 404s via proxy, works locally

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, http, proxy

I've previously had the issue that I couldn't pinpoint the culprit in my Django app, causing all requests to 404. [See the previous Stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262421/unable-to-pinpoint-djangos-reason-to-404-for-all-requests)

Since then I've tried to narrow down the issue and therefore started a new, VERY basic, Django app.

All the project consists of is:

```
$ django-admin startproject tempor
```

I've added the test directory and imported the test function

```
$ vi tempor/tempor/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from tempor.views import test

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/$', test),
]
```

The views.py and the test function

```
$ vi tempor/tempor/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
        return HttpResponse("OKAY")
```

Then I migrated the project - as suggested by Django:

```
$ python manage.py check

$ python manage.py migrate
```

Now I run the server:

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8282
```

Access from the server locally:

```
$ curl localhost:8282/test/
OKAY
$ curl <server-public-IP>:8282/test/
OKAY
```

Access from an external system (via proxy)

```
$ curl <server-public-IP>:8282/test/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
[...]
<h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
[...]
</html>
```

In the settings.py I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

If I don't use `'*'`, the external system is informed accordingly, as debugging is on:

```
$ curl <server-public-IP>:8282/test/
[...]
DisallowedHost at http://<server-public-IP>:8282/test/
[...]
```

---

This also occurs, if I try the same with a simple Python HTTP server - which the Django admin.py basically uses.

```
echo "OKAY" > /tmp/test/index.html
cd /tmp/test/
python -m http.server 8282
[...]
```

Local access:

```
$ curl localhost:8282/index.html
OKAY
$ curl <server-public-IP>:8282/index.html
OKAY
```

Remote access:

```
$ curl <server-public-IP>:8282/index.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
[...]
<p>Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.</p>
[...]
</html>
```

http.server log:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8282 ...
<server-public-ip> - - [<timestamp>] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<proxy-ip> - - [<timestamp>] code 404, message File not found
<proxy-ip> - - [<timestamp>] "GET http://<server-public-ip>:8282/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

For the moment, the proxy is a simple SSH port forwarding - which will later be replaces by an NGINX.

---

*edit:* The very same applies if I run `uwsgi` for the Django app:

```
$ uwsgi --http :8282 --module tempor.wsgi
```

Local accesses work - external requests 404.

---

**Why do requests via a proxy 404 for me and how can I fix this issue?**

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong with your Django setup but your proxy is broken as it tries to send an incorrect `GET` command. It _shouldn't_ include the hostname and port. Does it work for other web sites?

Comment: It's not really supposed to work for other websites - as that's just a temporary setup to access the Django project. I'll have to look into the proxying of the requests then. I guess SSH port forwarding wasn't the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved, but I don't understand why**.

The issue was the direct access to the Python server using SSH port forwarding. An intermediate Nginx resolved the problem.

[See my ServerFault question for further details.](https://serverfault.com/questions/853154/direct-python-server-access-with-ssh-port-forwarding-fails-but-succeeds-with-in)

For the server setup see the ServerFault question.

Client setup boils down to:

```
# SSH port forwarding, port 80 for Nginx access, port 8282 for direct Python webserver access
ssh -L 8181:<farawayhost-ip>:<80 or 8282> <sshuser>@<remotehost-ip>

# on a second terminal
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8181
curl <farawayhost-ip>
```

Comment: Can you put into your question the *exact* commands you run, in order? Your HTTP request would make sense if you had a `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable set or were calling `curl` with different command line arguments.

Comment: @Blender I've edited the question on ServerFault. I've used `export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8181` on the host, for `curl` to use the SSH port forwarding.
Thank you for the input, I've missed that part in the question/elaboration.

Comment: @Blender I've also extended the answer here.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. 127.0.0.1:8181 isn't an HTTP proxy, it's just proxying connections to a HTTP server over SSH. A HTTP proxy allows you to connect to arbitrary sites by having your client make requests like `GET http://...`, which your port forwarding does not do.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you!